# How to add form sections using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form that requires a user to input details of a family member. I'd like to show the fields for one family member, then have a button saying 'Click to add another family member', and my question is - how could I use jQuery to add an exact copy of the family member div/fieldset below the existing one when that is clicked?

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="family-member">
        <ul>
            <li>
              <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="first-name">
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="surname">Surname</label>
              <input type="text" name="surname">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a>Click to add another family member</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#add_more').click(function(e) {
        $(this).before($('.family-member:eq(0)').html());
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>   
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="family-member">
        <ul>
            <li>
              <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="first-name">
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="surname">Surname</label>
              <input type="text" name="surname">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a id="add_more" href="javascript:void(0);">Click to add another family member</a>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Would there be a way to add a span within the family-member div, that would increment by one each time, so I could display 'Family Member 1', 'Family Member 2' etc?

Answer (score 2):

What about getting the ul element and calling the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function on that and then appending it to the `<a>` tag using the `append()` or [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function. e.g.

```
var formHtml = $("ul").html();
$("a").append(formHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `html` and `append` methods:

```
var html = $('.family-member:eq(0)').html();
$('form').append(html);
```

The `eq(0)` is used to clone only the first "family member".